# Rusty metal vase, can I use it for vegetables?

Tags: vegetables

I am creating a small vegetable garden. I have a metal vase, that I particulary like, and want to use it. It's completely rusty inside.

Can the rust somehow, ruin the vegetables? If not, can that be somehow bad for the health by eating those vegetables?

Comment: eventually it may leak.

Answer (score 1):

It would be iron oxide which would be fine for plants and not a problem for us humans. Plants need and use iron.  Does this pot have drainage? Use potting soil and forget using rocks and gravel on the bottom (worsens drainage).  Otherwise I've used all kinds of wonderful rusty stuff for all kinds of plants and have never had a problem or have heard that it could be a problem. I worry about the stuff in our dang tap water far more; for plants, soil and for us to drink.  I water all my potted stuff with distilled water or well water.